# An example: Am I understanding GPU advantage correctly?

Tags: gpu

Just reading a bit about what the advantage of GPU is, and I want to verify I understand on a practical level.  Lets say I have 10,000 arrays each containing a billion simple equations to run.  On a cpu it would need to go through every single equation, 1 at a time, but with a GPU I could run all 10,000 arrays as as 10,000 different threads, all at the same time, so it would finish a ton faster...is this example spot on or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: You can multi-thread CPU programs as well. The answer requires a detailed explanation of architectures to fully explain why some parallel operations on GPUs are significantly quicker than CPUs. I'm not entirely sure what the purpose/detail this question requires?

Comment: So your saying the exact basic program above (it loads all those equations and runs them.  Done.) there are still other factors that need to be looked at before determining if GPU or CPU would computer it faster?  What else would you need to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call it spot on, but I think you're headed in the right direction. Mainly, a GPU is optimized for graphics-related calculations. This does not, however, mean that's all it is capable of.

Without knowing how much detail you want me to go into here, I can say at the very least the concept of running things in parallel is relevant. The GPU is very good at performing many tasks simultaneously in one go (known as running in parallel). CPUs can do this too, but the GPU is specifically optimized to handle much larger numbers of specific calculations with preset data.

For example, to render every pixel on your screen requires a calculation, and the GPU will attempt to do as many of these calculations as it can all at the same time. The more powerful the GPU, the more of these it can handle at once and the faster its clock speed. The end result is a higher-end GPU can run your OS and games in 4k resolution, whereas other cards (or integrated graphics) might only be able to handle 1080p or less.

There's a lot more to this as well, but I figured you weren't looking for the insanely technical explanation.

The bottom line is this: For running a single task on one piece of data, the CPU will normally be faster. A single CPU core is generally much faster than a single GPU core. However, they typically have many cores and for running a single task on many pieces of data (so you have to run it once for each), the GPU will usually be faster. But these are data-driven situations, and as such each situation should be assessed on an individual basis to determine which to use and how to use it.

Comment: So, I'm reading your answer as, given the exact example program example I gave (it loads all those billions of separate equations and needs to run them. Done.) That yes, unless you did something really wrong, or have the worst GPU ever, you should be able to run that specific task a ton faster on a GPU then a cpu. Ya?

Comment: Well you didn't give an exact example. You said you had 10,000 arrays of equations (What does that mean exactly? I'm not familiar with any class or struct that is literally an equation.) You also said there were billions of each equation. Did you mean to say you have 10,000 arrays with billions of numbers inside, and you wish to perform the same calculation on all of them? I guess my point is you'll need to be more specific on what your use case is. What is the data going in, what is the data going out, and what is the operation being performed on the data. Hence, data-driven.

Comment: To clarify further. If you had 100,000 arrays, each with 100,000 integers in them, and you needed to take every set of 2 arrays and add each of their members together such that [1, 2, 3, 4] + [2, 3, 4, 5] = [3, 5, 7, 9], a GPU would be capable of performing this task much faster.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Lets make it more specific examples then, and see how it matters accordingly.  I was under the assumption it didn't matter what was being calculated,so long as it could be broken to many parallel threads.  VERSION1: Let's say each "equation" in the array is actually an array of numbers to be added together, so like [[1,5],[2,1]] calculate to [6,3].  VERSION2: Let's say each "equation" is a string, like "1+(5/6)*9" which needs to be parsed and then calculate the answer.  VERSION 3: Each array is actually 1 billion numbers, and it needs to alternate +/- for every #. (ie.1+3-5+18...)

Comment: Version 1 and 3 are faster on the GPU. Version 2 is going to be difficult to even program properly on a GPU, but assuming you did, it would still likely be faster to do it on the CPU.

Comment: sounds to me like you can't just toss a random function and a giant parameter list to one of the cores on a GPU and say "GO!", like you can to CPU, instead you need everything formatted as a basic repeatable pattern of numbers and operators before you can send a task to GPU.

Comment: Well typically you'd be using more than a single core, but yes, it is not as simple to just throw together some code for a GPU as it is for a CPU. I'm not certain what your level of understanding is here (are you a programmer or just a curious techie) but look into shader code if you're interested. With GPUs, you focus on placing the data you want where you want it, writing some shader code that will operate on that data in parallel, then retrieving your result. If this has helped you I would appreciate it if you accepted this answer (click the little check mark). :P

Comment: My understanding is pretty minimal, I'm just a lowly but curious javascript programmer.  GPU's are way above my pay grade, but curious to understand what I can about it; How exactly they are an advantage and why it is challenging.  Check mark clicked! Thanks!